# Most elegant way to get two properties at the same time

Tags: groovy

Suppose you have hierarchical data and want to obtain the merged value of separate properties, what is the most elegant, or *groovy*, way to do so?

The following example holds information about failed and skipped tests. Of course, it does make sense, that these values are separated - but for the use case of retrieving a list of all tests, that did not run successfully, I came across two possible solutions, which both of them did not satisfy me.

```
def junitResultList = [
    [
        name: "Testsuite A",
        children: [
            failedTests: ["Test 1", "Test 2"],
            skippedTests: []
        ]
    ],
    [
        name: "Testsuite B",
        children: [
            failedTests: ["CursorTest"],
            skippedTests: ["ClickTest", "DragNDropTest"]
        ]
    ]
]
```

To be more specific, I want the value to be `["Test 1", "Test 2", "CursorTest", "ClickTest", "DragNDropTest"]`.

The first approach was simply to perform an addition of the spread test lists:

```
(junitResultList*.children*.failedTests + 
 junitResultList*.children*.skippedTests).flatten()
```

While this works, it appeared to me that specifying the path to these properties twice seems not to be the most groovy way, so I came up with this horrible but somehow appealing disasterpiece:

```
(junitResultList*.children*.findAll {
    ['skippedTests', 'failedTests'].contains(it.key)
})*.values().flatten()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your initial expression to something like this:

```
junitResultList.children.collect { it.failedTests + it.skippedTests }.flatten()
```

or

```
junitResultList.children.collect { [it.failedTests, it.skippedTests] }.flatten()
```

Comment: This one-liner is very readable and clearly shows its intention.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do as below:

```
//Define the keys to find
def requiredKeys = ['failedTests', 'skippedTests']
println requiredKeys.collect{ junitResultList.children."$it"}.flatten()
```

You can quickly try the same online <kbd>[demo](http://ideone.com/XzjAEK)</kbd>

Comment: That's really smart!

Comment: @Jazzschmidt, appreciate if you can accept it as answered & up vote if the answer is is helpful.

Comment: Did an upvote, but want to see some more possibilities. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `subMap()`s and then the `values()` on that:

```
junitResultList*.children*.subMap(["failedTests","skippedTests"])*.values().flatten()
```